# aspx the event Onchange of my dropdownlist does not work

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Hello I have a problem with a page that I am resetting, the page is already a bit old, it is made with vb.net.

The problem is that when changing the item in a dropdownlist it does not reflect the change.

**Aspx code**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ModificaTitulo.aspx.vb" Inherits="Libros.ModificaTitulo"%>

<%@ Register Assembly="RJS.Web.WebControl.PopCalendar.Net.2008" Namespace="RJS.Web.WebControl"
    TagPrefix="rjs" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="App_Themes/TABContent/AjaxControlToolkit.Tabs.Tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#f1f2d0">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    
             
 </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>   
<table align ="center" style="width: 304px; height: 54px;" ><tr>
                                <td align ="right" ><asp:Label runat="server" Text="Libro:" ID="Label1" 
                                        Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>
</td><td align ="left" ><asp:DropDownList ID="Existe2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Font-Names="MS Reference Sans Serif" Font-Size="9pt" Width="183px">
</asp:DropDownList>
                       </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>  
</td></tr></table>
```

**aspx.vb code**

This is where the listener method of the dropdownlist is in the codebehind "ModificaTitulo.aspx.vb" but it does not detect the method or send me any error, I already did everything but I can not find the problem, try adding the method directly to the dropdownlist "OnSelectedChanged = 'Existe2_SelectedIndexChanged' "but it didn't work.

```
    Protected Sub Existe2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Existe2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim myScript as String = "window.alert('Cambio el selector');"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myScript", myScript, True)
    End Sub
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the event is firing, or is the code not workig?

I would bring up the property sheet.

this:
[image]

Now, just empty out the event stub, tab out

Now, double click on the event setting - see what event it wires up for you. And consider putting in a break point in that routine.